# how to add UINavigationController UIToolbar to the top of the view not the bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I am trying to add a the `UINavigationController` `UIToolbar` to the top of the view, (under the navigation controller.

My view is a `UITableViewController`... so there is that to deal with. Currently I am just positioning the `UIToolbar` that appears at the bottom of the view where I want it to display using

```
[self.navigationController.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 30)];
```

this positions the toolbar in the correct place I would like it to appear, However there is a problem with where its positioned, which I will explain.

When you set a `UINavigationController` toolbar to be displayed it puts itself at the bottom of the view and pushes the UITableView up so the toolbar does not cover the tableview. However when I change the position of the toolbar the tableview still thinks the toolbar is at the bottom of the screen meaning the toolbar does not meet flush at the bottom of the screen how I would like it too.

So my question is how can I get the toolbar to display directly below the navigation controller bar and push the tableview down abit to accommodate for the toolbar in its new position.

I hope this all makes sense, Any help I would like to than in advance and below is the current code I am using (all be it basic I am still abit perplexed about whats going on behind the scenes for this to happen).

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
//..

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 30)];
    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

//..
}
```

## update

this is currently what the toolbar is doing to my tableview

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call setFrame on your UITableView to move it into positon.

```
float y = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y + self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height;
[myTable setFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-y)];
```

Comment: do you think its possible to call it on self.tableView? I have used a tableViewController.. so I am not sure how to call it on mytable as I have not set one. I have just been using self.tableview, however when I used your code with self.tableView it dose not seem to be working.

Comment: Yes, myTable is just a placeholder for whatever your UITableView ivar is. How did you create your table? In Interface Builder or in code? You may have auto resizing turned on which is overriding the setFrame command.

Comment: In Interface Builder I added a UItableView and passed the view to it in their.. I just looked for autor resizing, I saw a auto resizing subviews which I just deselected but that didnt help.. is there another I can look for.

Comment: BOYA! I just deselected clip subview, re-ran the script and the table goes to the bottom now! however the toolbar still covers the first row slightly.

Comment: check out the update to my question to see what the toolbar is doing to the tableview.

Comment: It looks like you need to add 20 for the status bar above the nav bar. Try putting your toolbar at 64 (20 + 44) and your table at 94 (20 + 44 + 30) and tell me if that fixes it. The height of the table should then be 480-94. And make sure auto-resizing is turned off for the table and toolbar.

Comment: gah! cannot get this to work.. also I have noticed at the bottom when the cells are about to go out of view or come back into view the dissipear then leave that space at the bottom of the tableview untill the next reappears... odd.

Comment: I changed Y to this.. and it dose not change where the tableview starts unfortunatly

float y = ((self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y + self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height) + 20 );

Comment: So I got it working in the end but I ended up having to make a new viewController that was view based and put a uitableview inside that and give that tableview the delegates and datasource via interface builder.. then the code worked perfectly.